# foundation for apps can't load js and css files

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

i installed all foundation for apps dependencies successfully including ruby, nodejs, git, scss and everything.

however, the it seems to have problem with loading its properties.

it shows the screen below (without template, css, and js)

[image: my screen]

when it should be showing the one below

[image: proper screen]

judging by the chrome and ie console, it clearly is a problem of my local settings.
does anyone know how to fix this?

below is my chrome console error i got running the welcome template.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:8080/assets/js/angular.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   foundation.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
>   http://localhost:8080/assets/css/app.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you try installing it again and see if there are any errors while installing, you have some files missing from the package I think...I am trying to install myself in mean time...

Comment: @Vishwanath I reinstalled it. and found a error while building an app. it reads: "gulp-ruby-sass: stderr ..... (Bundler: GemNotFound)" interesting..

Comment: Check step 1 of this http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html `gem install bundler` I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After starting your app by running the **gulp** tasks, a folder named `build` will be generated inside your project containing the `assets` folder and all those required files that the navigator has failed to load.

Get a look inside it, if you don't find them then it may be related to installation or configuration issues. it's better to try installing again in this case.

But if everything is where it suppose to be then its probably a port conflict issue, other app in your computer may be using http://localhost:8080, in this case you will need to open **`gulpfile.js`** and go to the line where it starts the test Server :

```
// Starts a test server, which you can view at http://localhost:8080
gulp.task('server', ['build'], function() {
  gulp.src('./build')
    .pipe($.webserver({
      port: 8080,
      host: 'localhost',
      fallback: 'index.html',
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }))
  ;
});
```

Change `port: 8080` to `port: 8081` or any thing else, restart your gulp tasks to recreate the new server and it will works if the new port is available `http://localhost:8081`.

I had the exact same issue and it turned out that my apache server which is always opened to render my PHP files was using that port `:8080`.